# Separating handler configuration from web.config for IIS7 (configSource not supported?)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

For the system.web/httpHandlers section of web.config I can use the "configSource" attribute to specify an external configuration file, like so:

```
<system.web>
     <httpHandlers configSource="App_Config\httpHandlers_iis6.config" />
</system.web>
```

This allows me to use the same set of handlers across all of my environments while only having to maintain them in one place, while still allowing things like appSettings to change from one web.config to the next.

Unfortunately, it appears that the same technique is **not** supported for the section pertaining to IIS7 handlers:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers configSource="App_Config\httpHandlers_iis7.config" /> <!-- not supported -->
</system.webServer>
```

Is there any way to separate my handlers configuration from the main web.config file for IIS7?

Comment: I'd like to know this too. although reason is a little different. I want one section for IIS7.5 on 64bit, and one for IIS7.5 32bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah - I've got it.

Here's my line from the web.config:

```
<handlers configSource="App_Config\Handlers.xml" />
```

not the \ rather than the / (I got caught there)

and in my external file I've got:

```
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Write, Script, Execute">
          <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
          <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>


            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>

    ...
    ...
    ...
              <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST" preCondition="integratedMode" name="SpellChecker" path="GoogleSpellChecker.ashx" type="umbraco

.presentation.umbraco_client.tinymce3.plugins.spellchecker.GoogleSpellChecker,umbraco"/>
          <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" name="Elmah" path="/umbraco/elmah.axd" type="Westfield.Web.Application.SecureErrorLogPageFactory, Westfield.Web"/>
        </handlers>
```

And it worked :)

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: What you describe does not work for me. The system.webServer/handlers element does not support the "configSource" attribute.

Comment: Hi David. In my Web.config VS2010 underlines the configsource attribute saying it doesn't recognise it, but I can assure you it worked for me. I'd like to re-iterate, make sure you use a backslash, rather than a forward slash (that got me).

Comment: So I ignored it when it told me it doesn't recognise the attribute

Comment: Well I'll be damned, you're right! I could swear I tried this exact setup before, but I must have made a mistake the first time. Thanks!

Comment: The **runtime section** happily accepts the configSource attribute but it ***does not read the external file***